# Optional properties behavior in TypeScript constructor arguments and interface

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a TypeScript project where I have encountered an interesting behavior regarding optional properties in constructor arguments and interfaces. It seems that TypeScript allows me to pass an object with optional properties to a constructor, even when the constructor's argument type is a non-optional type.

```js
// StartPaymentReq Interface
export interface StartPaymentReq {
  email?: string;
}

// Payment Class
export class Payment {
  email: string;

  constructor(email: string) {
    this.email = email;
  }
}

// Inside some function or method
const { email }: StartPaymentReq = req.body; // Destructuring from req.body, email inferred as `string | undefined`

const payment = new Payment(email); // No TypeScript warning or error even if email can be undefined
```

Expected Behavior:

I expected TypeScript to raise a warning or error when passing an object with optional properties to the Payment constructor because the email property in the Payment class is not marked as optional.

Actual Behavior:

No warnings or errors are raised by TypeScript when I pass an object with optional properties to the Payment constructor, even though the constructor expects a non-optional string argument for the email property.

Questions:

1. Is this behavior intentional in TypeScript, allowing optional properties to be passed to a constructor expecting non-optional arguments?
2. Should TypeScript raise a warning or error in such cases to enforce stricter type checks during development?
3. What are the best practices to handle optional properties when constructing objects that expect non-optional arguments?

Comment: I do get an error [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZRk1gAVMBPAW2BQCVgBHOAbwCg45hLMEAbAfgBccAM4woyAOYBuVgF9WrAPRK4ZKjXgBhXphEjWoSLDjZd+tRWooW7Ttz7CxEpDMUdsEJM4Cu2GNAAFFw8vE7iUgCUthwcMAAWCCIAdCF8cAC89qGyHAoKyqoAkt4IACZ4IhDUcOg+SP4IXnDQcNQJEGWsnt7wYFaa9AzChMQw6tYwQ5kxcCrZ6WBQEGBoMOSIIi2UCDCoXXKy3V5icP0aNllIwADulhcwgeeTQ5GyQA), and it's not about the optionality. You are passing an object, while the constructor expects a string

Comment: would you look at code again

Comment: Consider enabling `strict` compilerOption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason for this is you do not have "[strict](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict)" set to true in your tsconfig. Typescript is just a super type of Javascript. So at it's most fundamental level, this will be able to compile to Javascript just fine. Javascript has no concept of "optional params" beyond simply not supplying them. This lax compilation of Typescript is useful if you have a JS project you want to convert to TS. It lets you compile JS like it is TS without everything failing so you can adopt slowly.

If you set strict to true in your config though, the TS compiler will assume EVERYTHING is fully and reliably typed, and will not compile anything that is not safe at runtime.